# Why is my ASP.Net MVC model not populating correctly?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid here, but I just can't figure out what!

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(ContactViewModel contactModel)
{
    var phones = contactModels.Phones; // <-- This works fine
    var emails = contactModels.Emails; // <-- Count is 1, but EmailViewModel data is all blank

    return Json(new { Success = true });
}
```

Models:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Type is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Type")]
    public long ContactTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length is 50 characters")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length is 50 characters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public PhoneViewModel[] Phones { get; set; }

    public EmailViewModel[] Emails { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Marketing Rep")]
    public long? MarketingRepId { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long PhoneTypeId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneType { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public bool? ToDelete { get; set; }
}

public class EmailViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long EmailTypeId { get; set; }
    public string EmailType { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool? ToDelete { get; set; }
}
```

Json from Fiddler:

```
{"Id":"38484","ContactTypeId":"762","FirstName":"First","LastName":"Last",
"Phones":[{"Id":46783,"PhoneType":"Home","PhoneTypeId":3,"Number":"555-5555",
"ToDelete":false}],"Emails":[{"Id":0,"EmailType":"Work","EmailTypeId":1,
"Address":"myemail@gmail.com","ToDelete":false}],"MarketingRepId":"0"}
```

Everything is transferring to the CustomerViewModel just fine except for the Emails.  The array shows 1 element, but when I set a breakpoint in VS and inspect the element, everything is null.

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Why is the Id for your emails 0? I think if you solve that you will have a populated emails array

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there was a model binder attached to EmailViewModel that was intercepting the data coming in and processing it incorrectly so that it was returning a null model.

I removed this model binder and everything works great.